# Read Json data response using php

Tags: php, json, janrain

How can I read a JSON data response using php? The response t comes after user authentication done from a third party. Primarily, I just want `displayName` and `preferredUsername` data.

**Json response:**

```
 {
      "stat": "ok",
      "profile": {
        "providerName": "testing",
        "identifier": "http://testing.com/58263223",
        "displayName": "testing",
        "preferredUsername": "testing",
        "name": {
          "formatted": "testing"
        },
        "url": "http://testing.com/testing/",
        "photo": "https://securecdn.testing.com/uploads/users/5826/3223/avatar32.jpg?1373393837",
        "providerSpecifier": "testing"
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Doesn't `json_decode()` do what you want? Did you search the PHP documentation for "json" to see if it had anything useful?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `json_decode`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to decode your result then retrieve the value:

```
$json_data = '{
      "stat": "ok",
      "profile": {
        "providerName": "testing",
        "identifier": "http://testing.com/58263223",
        "displayName": "testing",
        "preferredUsername": "testing",
        "name": {
          "formatted": "testing"
        },
        "url": "http://testing.com/testing/",
        "photo": "https://securecdn.testing.com/uploads/users/5826/3223/avatar32.jpg?1373393837",
        "providerSpecifier": "testing"
      }
    }';

$json = json_decode($json_data);

echo $json->profile->displayName;
echo $json->profile->preferredUsername;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 <?php
$json='{
      "stat": "ok",
      "profile": {
        "providerName": "testing",
        "identifier": "http://testing.com/58263223",
        "displayName": "testing",
        "preferredUsername": "testing",
        "name": {
          "formatted": "testing"
        },
        "url": "http://testing.com/testing/",
        "photo": "https://securecdn.testing.com/uploads/users/5826/3223/avatar32.jpg?1373393837",
        "providerSpecifier": "testing"
      }
    }';


    $data=json_decode($json ,true);
     $preferredUsername=$data['profile']['preferredUsername'];
     $displayName=$data['profile']['displayName'];

    ?>
```

Comment: Yes. By using ```$data=json_decode($json ,true);``` we can convert all object to the array.

Answer (score 2):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is what you're looking for:

```
$json = '[
    {
        "displayName": "testing",
        "preferredUsername": "testing",
    }
]';

$jsonArray = json_decode($json);

foreach($jsonArray as $value){
    $displayName = $value->Display Name;
    $preferredUsername = $value->Preferred User;
}
```