# Read Json results in php

Tags: php, soap

I have a soap request to a server which works successfully and return json data.

```
{"GetAccountResult":{"Header":{"Rquid":"D560BC95-24F2-F705-0585-7CCB38E37ECE","Status":{"StatusCode":"-4","Message":"Account not found","Details":null}},"Account":null}}
```

I would like to know how to access that in php and only print the **Message**? not the entire json results?

I have tried

```
$account   = $client->GetAccount($arrParams);
            $results = json_encode($account);

            echo $results->Message;
```

But this still prints the full json object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON file with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php)

Comment: You can see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865544/read-json-data-response-using-php

Comment: your must use json_decode, not encode

Comment: @Hooli I have tried that but still get an empty response

Comment: @user1, check out my answer. It will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$account   = '{"GetAccountResult":{"Header":{"Rquid":"D560BC95-24F2-F705-0585-7CCB38E37ECE","Status":{"StatusCode":"-4","Message":"Account not found","Details":null}},"Account":null}}';
$results = json_decode($account,true);    // 2nd argument `true` returns array from JSON
echo $results['GetAccountResult']['Header']['Status']['Message'];
```

Comment: Its empty.  should print `Account not found`

Comment: If you leave the `true` parameter or set to `false` you will get an object. Makes easier in this context to get the value.

Comment: @user1, I assumed that the first line of code gives the JSON you have mentioned in the question. But if I replace that line with the JSON, it prints `Account not found`.

Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks now worlks, will accet in 3 mins

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = json_decode($your_json, true);

$message = $result["GetAccountResult"]["Header"]["Status"]["Message"];
```

I would strongly recommend to use `isset()` to check if the indices exist. Otherwise you may end up with errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data by json_decode:

```
$json = '{"GetAccountResult":{"Header":{"Rquid":"D560BC95-24F2-F705-0585-7CCB38E37ECE","Status":{"StatusCode":"-4","Message":"Account not found","Details":null}},"Account":null}}';
$t =  json_decode($json,true);
print_r($t['GetAccountResult']['Header']['Status']['Message']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

```
$account   = $client->GetAccount($arrParams);
$results   = json_decode($account);

echo $results->GetAccountResult->Header->Status->Message;
```